# what is the means of (0 -> 1) of series expansion

Tags: equation-solving, functions, simplifying-expressions, output-formatting

I use mathematica 8 to take a taylor expansion.In the Output, the expression (0->1) appears in the second term and all higher order term, and this expression is multiplied with other coefficient and variable in every term.

I have knew that The '->' is the rule for variable and a expression, but I can not understand why the number "0" can be replace by number "1".

code:

```
FullSimplify[Series[-((8 kb^2 T^2 (-2 π^2 vf +   
   g kf^2 Log[π + (2 ωd)/(kb π T)]))/(
 7 g kf^2 Zeta[3])), {T, Tc, 2}], 
 Assumptions -> {g > 0 && g ∈ Reals && hb ∈ Reals &&
 hb > 0 && ωd ∈ Reals && ωd > 0 && 
kf ∈ Reals && kf > 0 && kb ∈ Reals && kb > 0 && 
m > 0 && m ∈ Reals && T > 0 && 
T ∈ Reals && γ > 0 && γ ∈ Reals &&
 vf > 0 && vf ∈ Reals}]
```

out:

```
e -> -((8 kb^2 Tc^2 (-2 π^2 vf + 
   g kf^2 Log[γ + (2 ωd)/(kb π Tc)]))/(
7 g kf^2 Zeta[3]))) + (
 16 kb^2 Tc ((2 π^2 vf)/(g kf^2) + ωd/(
kb π Tc γ + 2 ωd) - 
Log[γ + (2 ωd)/(kb π Tc)]) **(0 -> 1)** (T - Tc))/(
 7 Zeta[3])+...
```

question:what the meaning of this expression?

Comment: Please, add the code you used to generate the series.

Comment: Thanks @Sektor, I add the code and output

Comment: Please, go to the help centre and format the code properly. You can substitute the backslash escaped symbols with the corresponding characters.

Comment: Quit the kernel and try it again. It looks to me like you've already defined a term you're working with.

Comment: @PatrickStevens thanks a lot! I am formatting my question, It's my 1st time ask question, I am not practiced the formatting technique

Comment: @Sektor How to type the greek "pi"?

Comment: [Lookie here](http://bfy.tw/PqH)

Comment: @alxandernashzhang Thanks for formatting the post.  Fixing the Greek letters is not that easy, so don't worry about that for now.  This almost certainly happens because one of the variables in your original expressions was already defined to some value that contained `0 -> 1`.  This `0 -> 1` thing was not generated by the commands you show.  It must have come from a previous, perhaps accidental definition.

Comment: @Sektor I can't fully open the site, and I also can not type the "element"

Comment: After the re-formatting by @Szabolcs (thanks a lot for your answer), It's work, How to do it?

Comment: @PatrickStevens I quit the kernel and clear all used variable, But there are also the (0->1) expression.

Comment: @Szabolcs  I quited the kernel and cleared all used variable, But there are also the (0->1) expression. And I also don't understand you means "some value that contained 0 -> 1". How to deal with the problem?

Comment: This is what I get in a fresh kernel (note `In[1]`) in version 9: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gkfh1yx4pc0q0sf/Screenshot%202015-09-07%2012.15.48.png?dl=0  Are you sure you are not evaluating anything else before trying the *exact* example you posted?

Comment: @Szabolcs Before the Series expansion, I also solve a equation, and the formula be expanded is the answer  of the Solve. I refer to this answer by "%", in this case, The (0 -> 1) appears.Is it the source of the problem?